# come to mind or came to mind

Tags: word-choice, tense

> When we were trying to find a medium to hold the cracks, the use of ceramics **came to mind**. With some ceramics in stock, we began to experiment different mixing ratio ...

I am learning English grammar rules, pardon me of the elementary question. I did a search and it seems both are acceptable.

I was told I should use *came to mind* because I am narrating the sequence of events that happened in the past. However, the idea to use ceramics is still present and relevant, is using *come to mind* a better choice than *came to mind*?

Comment: were trying/came, of course. am trying/come

Comment: Thanks @Lambie If I were to use `we are trying`, then using `come to mind` will be right despite I am narrating a sequence of events that happened in the past?

Answer (score 1):

"Came to mind" is better, unless you are talking about a new, undeveloped idea.

For example,

When we **consider** what we can do to ease the problem, several ideas **come** to mind, such as ceramics, super glue, and funny putty.

When we **considered** what to do, ceramics **came** to mind, and we started to experiment with them.

Comment: The key point here, surely, is that the tense of 'come' must match the tense of 'consider'?

Comment: Yes, but I introduced the word *consider* , which doesn't appear in the OP, to point out that the tense of *come* isn't a free choice.

Comment: _Came to mind_ accords with _were trying_, surely?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to understand that `Come` or `came` are both correct depends if `we were trying` or `we are trying` is used? It doesn't matter if the events is in the past or present?

Comment: @FlyingPenguin If you use "we were trying", that means that the events *were* in the past. The time of the action is the reason the verb tense is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

"Come to mind" is to get an idea, initially.  In other words, it indicates a beginning, it's not the same as the idea just being present in an on-going way.

"Yesterday a stray dog came to our house, and today we still have the dog".

"Yesterday an idea came to mind, and today we still have the idea".

You still have the dog, but that doesn't mean the dog is still arriving; likewise, you still have the idea, but that doesn't mean the idea is still arriving.